# Is $\{f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] \mid f(1,0) = f(0,1) = 0\}$ a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> Is $\{f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] \mid f(1,0) = f(0,1) = 0\}$ a prime ideal?

I don't believe so, but I don't quite trust my reasoning.

For $I = \{f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y] \mid f(1,0) = f(0,1) = 0 \}$ to be a prime ideal, we require that either $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/I$ to be an integral domain or that, for all $ab \in I$, either $a \in I$ or $b \in I$. However, if $ab \in I$, then this implies that $(ab)(1,0) = (ab)(0,1) = 0$. It could then be the case that the polynomial $a$ at $(1,0)$ is $0$ but is nonzero at $(0,1)$, and likewise the polynomial $b$ could be $0$ at $(0,1)$ but nonzero at $(1,0)$. Therefore, we have that $ab \in I$ but neither $a$ nor $b$ in I.

Comment: Actually $I=(x-1,y)\cap(x,y-1)$, and clearly $xy\in I$, but $x\notin I$ and $y\notin I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Consider for example $f(x,y) = x - 1$ and $g(x,y) = y - 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the explicit example, that helps a lot.

Comment: (+1) @Jmars: To supplement Ethan's post, note that to prove that $I$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb R[x,y],$ you would need to prove the following universal statement: "For all $f,g\in \Bbb R[x,y],$ if $f\cdot g\in I,$ then $f\in I$ or $g\in I.$" (cont'd)

Comment: To prove that $I$ is *not* such an ideal, you would need to prove the following existential statement: "There exist $f,g\in\Bbb R[x,y]$ such that $f\cdot g\in I,$ but $f,g\notin I.$" Your reasoning gives you an idea what such functions $f,g$ would need to look like, but to actually finish the proof, you need prove that such $f,g$ actually exist. The simplest (perhaps only) way to do so is by providing concrete examples of such functions $f,g.$